# How do I interpret this error from GDB?

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

I feel pretty dumb right now, but how do I interpret this message in GDB?

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fe2eb46073a in clearerr (fp=0x4359790) at clearerr.c:27
27  clearerr.c: No such file or directory.
    in clearerr.c
```

What file is missing that's causing the segfault? Is it clearerr.c or the file that clearerr is trying to access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What file is missing that's causing the segfault?

We don't know what is causing `SIGSEGV`, but it's unlikely that any missing file has anything to do with it.

First, this:

```
clearerr.c: No such file or directory.
```

simply means that GDB can not show you the source where `SIGSEGV` occurred. That is because `clearerr()` is part of your `libc`, and you either didn't install sources for your `libc` (they may not even be available for your environment), or you didn't tell GDB how to find these sources.

Second, the actual cause of `SIGSEGV` is most likely because the `fp` that you invoked it with has been corrupted or is invalid in some other way.

Here are a few ways this could happen:

```
 char c;
 FILE *fp = (FILE*) &c;  // fp is bogus: doesn't point to a FILE at all
 clearerr(fp);           // likely will crash

 FILE *fp2;              // fp2 contains uninitialized garbage
 clearerr(fp2);          // likely will crash

 FILE *fp3 = fopen("/tmp/foo", "w");
 fclose(fp3);            // destroys fp3
 clearerr(fp3);          // accesses dangling memory, likely will crash
```

There are of course many other ways as well. You'll need to look at the *caller* of `clearerr` to see if it's doing something stupid. To find the caller, use GDB `where` command.

Answer (score -2):

The seg fault is being caused by a file that clearerr.c is trying to access (at line 27).